# How to convert dictionary to json if the value of dictionary is list in node js?

Tags: json, node.js

I know that how can I convert dictionary to JSON but I could not find a way if the value of dictionary is list. Please help me !!

```
dic = {
       'key1': ["value1", "value3"],
       'key2': ["value2", "value4"] 
      }
```

For example, this code is from node js. I would like to see the results like that:

```
{
 {
  'key1': 'value1',
  'key2': 'value2'
 },
 {
  'key1': 'value3',
  'key2': 'value4'
 },
}
```

I think I am clear. Thanks in advance !!
Note: I am trying to do this in Node JS

Comment: That's not valid syntax. maybe you want: `[{ key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }, { key1: 'value3', key2: 'value4' }];`

Comment: Yeahh you're right, sorry for my synax. Do you have any solution ? :)